# Android Kotlin: Is it possible to store the LastLocation in a variable?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use the last known location of an Android user as a variable for a separate coroutine API call

```
 private fun getLocation()  {
        lateinit var latLong: String
        val client: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext())
        client.lastLocation
        val location = client.lastLocation
        location.addOnSuccessListener {
            latLong = "${it.latitude},${it.longitude}"
         }
         makeApiCall(latLong)}
}
```

Is it possible to force a wait for the `addOnSuccessListener` to ensure the variable is updated accordingly?

Comment: Why don't you just call `makeApiCall(latLong)` inside your OnSuccessListener instead?

Comment: You also have to keep in mind, there might not ever be a success state. The user might have location services turned off. If you don't want to have to work with this callback, you can get the last known location directly from LocationManager synchronously. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

Comment: The `makeAPICall(latLong)` is a part of a different suspension function so when I try to do so I am greeted with ` Suspension functions can only be called within coroutine body`. I've seen a few examples where they are applying all changes within the OnSuccessListener but I'm hoping to find a way to pull them out of that

Comment: Is this function a suspend function? It doesn't say that in your code above.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I didn't know about this thank you (synchronous LocationManager) , do you happen to have an example I could work with please?

Comment: You have to select a provider. Below just looks for GPS, but you could use the `getProviders()` with a Criteria to provide fallbacks in case GPS is off. Maybe do something like this (haven't used it myself in like 8 years): `val location: android.location.Location? = (context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager).run { getLastKnownLocation(getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) }` It will be null if none is currently available. This is probably not the same Location class as the one used by the Google API.

Comment: This synchronous call is only available for getting the last location known to the device. It could be kind of out-of-date if nothing on the device has requested an updated location recently. But I assume it's the same thing you get with FusedLocationProviderClient when asking for "last known". Not sure why FusedLocationProviderClient requires a callback for getting it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think you've found the solution to my problem! Thank you! I'm new here how do I mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. Comments can't be accepted as answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the last known location synchronously by working directly with Android's LocationManager.

```
val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
val location: Location? = with(locationManager) {
    val provider = getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
    getLastKnownLocation(provider) 
}
```

If you want a fallback in case GPS is off, you can use the `getProviders()` function with a Criteria argument. In either case, all location services might be turned off by the user, so the result might be a null Location.

Note: You can also convert Java callbacks into suspend functions using `suspendCoroutine`. Something like this:

```
/** Await the result of a task and return its result, or null if the task failed or was canceled. */
suspend fun <T> Task<T>.awaitResult() = suspendCoroutine<T?> { continuation ->
    if (isComplete) {
        if (isSuccessful) continuation.resume(it.result)
        else continuation.resume(null)
        return@suspendCoroutine
    }
    addOnSuccessListener { continuation.resume(it.result) }
    addOnFailureListener { continuation.resume(null) }
    addOnCanceledListener { continuation.resume(null) }
}
```

Then if your function were a suspend function, you could use it like this:

```
private suspend fun getLocation()  {
    val client: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext())
    val location = client.lastLocation.awaitResult()
    val latLong = location?.run { "$latitude,$longitude" } ?: "null"
    makeApiCall(latLong)
}
```

(Just an example. Don't know what you want to pass to `makeApiCall` if you don't have a location, or if you want to call it at all.)

Comment: It was very concise. But why null string, why not just let it be null.

Comment: It's just an example. I have no idea what `makeApiCall` is expecting.

Comment: Ah! okay didn't refreshed the answer 

Comment: awesome extension function! but instead of it i had to use this :)